# How do I speed-up latex compile time?

Tags: performance, compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speeding up LaTeX compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8791/speeding-up-latex-compilation)

Currently am using Miktex and TexNicCenter to create pdf files including vector(.eps) and raster(.png) images. Compile time is about 6 seconds for 10 pages of text and 10 images, which is much slower than others have reported. I can compile to dvi instead of pdf (minus the raster images) in 1 second, but need to see the layout with the raster images.

Is there something that would slow down the pdf compile this much? epstopdf is used when compiling to pdf so that the .eps files can be included, but the total time for these conversions appears to be only ~0.5 seconds. Should I instead be pursuing a method of including raster images in dvi compiles?

Compile times for pdf:
no text, no figures: 1 second
text, no figures: 1 second
text, figures: 6 seconds

Compile times for dvi:
no text, no figures: 1 second
text, no figures: 1 second
text, vector figures: 1 second

Raster images are small ~200KB.

Answer (score 3):

Compiling to DVI, as mentioned in your analysis of times, is very fast. This is because the **D**e**v**ice **I**ndependent format does not embed the images. For more on this, see: [Why does LaTeX not embed imported EPS images into the DVI file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20781/5764)

You can see whether the images cause the slowdown in compile time by following TeX's output as it compiles. At page shipout, the page components are built and written to file. So, you'll see when TeX outputs the filename (of the image) it is busy with/processing. Remember also that processing of vector graphic images (EPS) may also be slow if they are complex. Typically, the complexity is associated with a larger file size, even in EPS.

For production purposes, you may consider using

```
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
```

in your document preamble. This will replace all images with 150pt x 100pt black rectangle (unless other dimensions are specified manually). Once you're ready for the final version of the document, remove the `demo` package option.

Comment: The pdf compilation output text seems to slow down for ~0.5 seconds total when processing the images as I stated above, so that isn't what's taking up the time. The eps images are relatively simple, yet one that literally only contains 100 circles slows the process by 0.5-1 second. The reason for my compiling repeatedly is to test the layout with images, and currently using dvi defeats this purpose.